# A balanced diet with the minimum carbon footprint

Tags: proteins, food, diet, carbohydrates, vegetable

Many studies shows that 1 kg of non-vegetarian food as 3-4 times more carbon footprint than 1 kg of vegetarian food. I think that does not represent the complete picture food from animal sources are rich in some nutrients. For example pound for pound fish will be much richer in protein than normal vegetables to so get the same amount of protein as from fish, we will have to eat lot more vegetables. So at the end of the day, the net carbon footprint of our protein requirement might be much closer between veg and non-veg food. Similarly for carbohydrates, cereals may be the most carbon efficient than any animal source.

**Question**: I am interested in a balanced diet with the minimum overall carbon footprint. Any reference or studies on what is the minimum carbon footprint with which we can get say 100 g of all the essential nutrients such as carbohydrates, proteins, vitamins, omega acids, saturated fats etc.

Comment: Can you provide a link to one or two of the studies you refer to so they can be evaluated for trustworthiness? Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it is concerned with dietary advice rather than Biology in the terms of SE Biology.

Comment: @David Sure but can you recommend any other stack-exchange site where this question could be more appropriate? Also, question is not a dietary advice which are everywhere but rather I am asking for a balanced which minimizes carbon footprint.

Comment: @anongoodnurse This link has a lot of details: https://ourworldindata.org/environmental-impacts-of-food

Comment: The carbon footprint really depends on non-biological factors, such as how your food is grown or harvested, processed, and transported to you.  If you eat fruit & vegetables grown in your own garden, or fish you catch yourself, there really is no carbon footprint.  If your fresh fruit is shipped in by air from another continent, and your fish is caught by a factory trawler working the Southern ocean, then the same diet has a very high carbon footprint.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I, too, found some interesting (and seemingly reliable) support for your initial statement.

Comment: This question may be on topic at the Sustainable Living site. https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/